# Do AWS-SAM templates support lifecycleconfiguration settings?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

Does anyone know if SAM templates support Lifecycleconfigruation settings? I see within standard cloudformation definitions you can define the lifecycle of objects like:

```
BucketName: "Mys3Bucket"
      LifecycleConfiguration:
        Rules:
        - AbortIncompleteMultipartUpload:
            DaysAfterInitiation: 7
          Status: Enabled
        - ExpirationInDays: 14
...
```

But this seems to fail when used in a SAM template. Am I doing something wrong or is this not part of the serverless application model definition?

Comment: SAM won't touch your S3 bucket definitions. All SAM does is to transform its own resources into CloudFormation resources. Your problem is therefore probably unrelated to SAM. To better diagnose this issue it'd be helpful if you could provide a complete CloudFormation template to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Could you include the error message you encounter when you try to use this property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me using the SAM CLI 1.15.0, although documentation seems sparse (hence my landing on this question while trying to figure it out).

The SAM template snippet below successfully creates a bucket and sets an appropriate lifecycle rule.

```yaml
Resources:
  Bucket1:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Sub "${BucketName}"
      AccessControl: Private
      VersioningConfiguration:
        Status: Enabled
      LifecycleConfiguration:
        Rules:
          - ExpirationInDays: 6
            Status: Enabled
```